# Can switching off computer’s power supply while it’s running damage the I/O?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, io, htpc, asus

Working on a HTPC build, and we accidentally switched off the PSU while it was running. Motherboard still runs and fans work, but video output and USB devices are no longer responding. Did we fry the motherboard, or is there a fix for this? So far, we’ve tried different monitors, different ports, different devices, and removing/restoring the CMOS battery.

Using an Asus Prime A620M-A motherboard with an AMD Ryzen 7 7700X.

Answer (score 1):

One can lose electric power and any computer goes off.

Generally, for one time, turning off the power does not do any damage.

Damage can occur, just generally not.

There may have been something about your motherboard that caused it to fail.

To your specific question:  Can switching off computer’s power supply while it’s running damage the I/O? Again, generally not.

The cheaper the engineering, the cheaper the parts, the cheaper the product, the more likely there may be some damage.

The better the engineering, the better the parts, the pricier the end product, it is not at all likely it will be damaged by a power outage.